# MSVS2015 Update 3 bug with template constructor not being recognized with constructor inheritance

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, constructor, visual-studio-2015

I've encountered a bug with MSVS2015 Update 3, and I hope to get some feedback on it.

I've already submitted a bug report at Microsoft connect here: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/3021085/bug-with-template-constructor-not-being-recognized-with-constructor-inheritance

At the time of writing, it seems that my attachments have not yet appeared on that site, so I will include the code to reproduce the problem here.

It occurs in the following scenario:

- There is a base template with a constructor which has a template parameter as its parameter
- There is a class that inherits the above base template for a specific type, which also inherits the base template's constructor
- There is another template with the same parameters as the base template, which inherits the base template's constructor and contains a conversion operator which returns an instance of the class above
- The derived class is included first, and then the derived template is included
- The constructor that the derived class has inherited from the base template is called

The above scenario is very specific, but there may be a more general underlying issue which I haven't been able to reproduce. I've encountered the bug in a project I'm working on, which happens to include the above scenario.

I have not found any ways around the problem.

Even though IntelliSense shows an error, the project will compile (and thus this is a bug).

It would be great if people could provide some feedback on if they are able to reproduce the bug and how the code to reproduce the bug could be simplified.
Any workarounds are welcome as well.

The source to reproduce the issue:

`Main.cpp`

```
#include "DerivedClass.h"

// If this include is left out, the bug disappears
#include "DerivedTemplate.h"

int main() {
    // The code below falsely reports that no suitable constructor exists to convert
    // from int to DerivedClass, however the code compiles fine
    DerivedClass test = 5;

    return 0;
}
```

`BaseTemplate.h`

```
#pragma once

// The BaseTemplate class must be in a namespace or the bug won't show up
namespace BaseTemplates {
    template <typename Type>
    class BaseTemplate {
    public:
        BaseTemplate() {
        }

        BaseTemplate(const Type& value) {
        }
    };
}
```

`DerivedClass.h`

```
#pragma once

#include "BaseTemplate.h"

class DerivedClass : public BaseTemplates::BaseTemplate<int> {
    using BaseTemplate<int>::BaseTemplate;
};
```

`DerivedTemplate.h`

```
#pragma once

#include "DerivedClass.h"
#include "BaseTemplate.h"

template <typename Type>
class DerivedTemplate : public BaseTemplates::BaseTemplate<Type> {
    // If BaseTemplates:: is left out below, an error will be reported by
    // IntelliSense, even though the code will compile
    using BaseTemplates::BaseTemplate<Type>::BaseTemplate;

public:
    // This operator must be included for the bug to occur
    operator DerivedClass() {
        return DerivedClass();
    }
};
```

---

**EDIT:**

<s>Compilation fails using Clang for Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 with the following build errors. After some changes I've brought it back to one error:</s>

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       call to implicitly-deleted default constructor of 'DerivedClass'    Bug C:\Users\qub1\Desktop\Bug\Bug\Bug\DerivedTemplate.h 13
```

Not sure if this is an issue with Clang, or Microsoft's compiler.

---

**EDIT 2:**

After inspecting the full error message Clang gave:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Bug, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  Main.cpp
1>  In file included from Main.cpp:5:
1>./DerivedTemplate.h(13,10): error : call to implicitly-deleted default constructor of 'DerivedClass'
1>                  return DerivedClass();
1>                         ^
1>  ./DerivedClass.h(5,22) :  note: default constructor of 'DerivedClass' is implicitly deleted because base class 'BaseTemplates::BaseTemplate<int>' has no default constructor
1>  class DerivedClass : public BaseTemplates::BaseTemplate<int> {
1>                       ^
1>Main.cpp(13,15): warning : unused variable 'test' [-Wunused-variable]
1>          DerivedClass test = 5;
1>                       ^
1>  1 warning and 1 error generated.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

It reports that the default constructor was implicitly deleted because the base class BaseTemplate has no default constructor, which is false, since it does have a base constructor. So this seems to be another (unrelated) bug in Clang.

---

**EDIT 3:**

Turns out I made a mistake and called the empty constructor (which obviously didn't exist). Fixed it.

Comment: @Yakk As stated, I ask if people are able to reproduce the bug and if it would be possible to make the code used to reproduce the bug smaller.

Comment: clang doesn't compile it in vs2015 u3

Comment: @doug Indeed it doesn't. I don't have much experience with compiling using clang, but it seems to be unable to find the BaseTemplate's constructor in the DerivedTemplate and the DerivedClass's constructor seems to be deleted. Not sure if this is an issue with clang or if Microsoft's compiler has things backwards again. Any idea on how to fix those problems?

Comment: After changing `using BaseTemplate<Type>::BaseTemplate;` in DerivedTemplate to `using BaseTemplates::BaseTemplate<Type>::BaseTemplate;` only one error remains, about calling an implicitly deleted constructor of DerivedClass.

Comment: I made a mistake, it turns out I needed a default constructor to make it compile with Clang. However, the original bug still exists.

Comment: I put in the needed default ctor which had been removed as there was another declared ctor and added the  'BaseTemplates:: ....' namespace prefix and don't see a problem in either compiler.

Comment: @doug Yeah it compiles successfully, however the bug is that IntelliSense still reports an error if `BaseTemplates::` is left out, even though the code will compile in MSVC. (It will fail in Clang however).

Comment: So the bug is that it shouldn't compile with `BaseTemplates::` left out and that intellisense and clang are correct?

Comment: @doug Yes I suppose it is. Although I'm not knowledgeable enough to say which is actually correct :) Just that there is a discrepancy.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that intellisense and clang are correct in flagging it. `using namespace_name::name` requires a namespace. It's not a using-declaration.